# How to delay second click on call button for some seconds in dialer in open cti

Tags: visualforce, cti, opencti

implemented dialer page using visualforce, @remoteAction javascript and Jquery.
Here the requirement is like when i click on call button more than one times, it should be ignored(Here we used jquery to initiate onclick event based on button id). How can i achieve that.

```
<apex:page standardController="contact" standardStylesheets="false">
<apex:slds />
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery}"/>

 <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock >
   <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
       <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Firstname}"/>  
       <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Lastname}"/>  
       <apex:inputField value="{!contact.AccountId}"/>   
   </apex:pageBlockSection>  
   <apex:pageBlockButtons >
   <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button--brand slds-button--neutral " value="JQuery Button" id="button1" onclick="buttonHide();"/>   
   </apex:pageBlockButtons> 
   </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>


</apex:page>
```

Script as below:

```
function buttonHide(){
alert("Alert for Button");
$(document).on('click','.button1',function(){
    document.getElementById(button1).disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function() { 
    document.getElementById(button1).disabled = true;false }, 3000);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you can prevent user from clicking the button second time. But once user click the button you can disabled the button.

So it will not allow user to click that again. You can easily do this in JavaScript

```
$(document).on('click','.transfer_btn',function(){
    document.getElementById(recId).disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById(recId).disabled = true;false }, 3000);
```

Comment: it has to ignore when i try to click more than one time with in 3 secs period.

Comment: @ApexCode then you can disable it and again enable it after 3 seconds using `setTimeout(function() { your_func(); }, 3000);
`

Comment: i have added my code above .where i have to add setTimeout. Please tell me. I am new for these cti and jquery.

Comment: @ApexCode check my updated answer.

Comment: @ApexCode yes you need to replace it with button id

Comment: Hi @Tushar , i am using below code. But it is not working.

Comment: Hi @Tushar i used like above but it is not working.

Comment: @ApexCode you can remove this line `$(document).on('click','.button1',function(){` and related brackets. As you are using JavaScript function so you don't need this.